# Sort a dictionary of arrays in python with a tuple as the key

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I a dictionary with a string tuple as the key and an array as the value:

```
some_dict = {}
some_dict[(A,A)] = [1234, 123]
some_dict[(A,B)] = [1235, 13]
some_dict[(A,C)] = [12, 12]
some_dict[(B,B)] = [12621, 1]
...
```

I am writing this to a csv file:

```
for k,v in some_dict.iteritems():
    outf.write(k[0]+","+k[1]+","+str(v[0])+","str(v[1])+"\n")
```

output:

```
A,A,1234,123
A,B,1235,13
A,C,12,12
B,B,12621,1
```

I'd like to sort it based on the first number "column" before writing to a file (or after and just rewrite?) so the output should be like:

```
B,B,12621,1
A,B,1235,13
A,A,1234,123
A,C,12,12
     ^ 
     Sorted on this 'column'
```

How do I do this? The file is very large, so doing it before writing would be better I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sort your dictionary items; the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) takes a `key` function to determine what to sort on; for the `(key, value)` tuple, use a lambda:

```
sorted_data = sorted(some_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1][0], reverse=True)
for (k1, k2), (v1, v2) in sorted_data:
```

I used `reverse=True` to have bigger values first.

Try to avoid reinventing the wheel, there is an excellent [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) available to you:

```
import csv

with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for (k1, k2), (v1, v2) in sorted(some_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda i: i[1][0]):
        writer.writerow([k1, k2, v1, v2])
```

and you won't have to explicitly convert the integers to strings either.

Comment: This is great. Sorted turns the dict into a list, correct?

Comment: @Jeff: `some_dict.iteritems()` yields a sequence, which sorted turns into a list, yes.

Comment: Is there a beginner tutorial / doc for lamda? Say I wanted to sort on the second column, or there are three columns (string, int, int) and I wanted to sort on the int?

Comment: @Jeff: the lambda is just a shortcut to create a function with one expression; `def anonymous(item): return item[1][0]` would be the function equivalent, only without having to name it. Each item sorted consists of `(key, value)`, so `item[1]` gets the value, and then you index into that. For a *second* column in the value, use `item[1][1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the [`sorted()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) builtin and specify a key by which to sort:

```
for k,v in sorted(some_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda t: t[1][0]):
    print k,v

#output:
(A, C) [12, 12]
(A, A) [1234, 123]
(A, B) [1235, 13]
(B, B) [12621, 1]
```

To order from large to small, simply set the `reverse` keyword argument:

```
for k,v in sorted(some_dict.iteritems(), key=lambda t: t[1][0], reverse=True):
```